# Subsets of intersection of two planes

Tags: linear-algebra

So I need to figure out if some sets are the subsets of the intersection of the two planes which are

$P_1: x + 3y + 2z = 7$

$P_2: 3z = y + 2x$

I have no idea how to find the intersection of two planes. Please help me with this question. Thank you.

Comment: The intersection of the two planes is given by all the points $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ satisfying *both* equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that normal vectors are

- $n_1=(1,3,2)$
- $n_2=(2,1,-3)$

which are not multiple therefore the intersection is a line with direction

$$v=n_1\times n_2 =(-11,7,-5)$$

and parametric equation

$$P(t)=P_0+vt$$

beeing $P_0$ any point in the intersection, that is for example

- $P_1: x + 3y + 2z = 7 \implies x=7-3y-2z$
- $P_2: 3z = y + 2x \implies 3z=y+2(7-3y-2z) \implies 5y+7z=14$

$$P_0=(3,0,2)$$

The cartesian equation for the line is given by the system of the two plane equations.